# Phone restart [Android - App Installation]

Tags: android, android-studio, installation

I've met an issue related with almost every phone but not Nexus.

During installation of app to phone by usb - Android Studio - phone restarts itself and app is not installing finally - I have to run app one more time by Android Studio to install it.

This doesn't happen all the time, but randomly, it's annoying and time wasting.

Honestly I don't know with what it's truly related problem, phones or Android Studio.

Have you met this problem?

Do you know any solutions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? And is your phone rooted?

Comment: Sorry but no. It happened on many phones in the past so I guess that it was something with Android Studio because I can't repeat it now.

Answer (score 2):

There are three cases:

1. There is a problem in the app source code: You should Build APK and install it in the phone. Maybe its required to install the app for several times. if phone restarted again, check the source code carefully.
2. There is a problem in usb cable: Maybe there is a short circuit in the cable or a glitch in it. Change cable and try again.
3. There is a problem in android studio: uninstall android studio and try to install it again.